# TypeScript and redux tool kit , createSlice: Assignment to property of function parameter 'state'

Tags: typescript, redux

Hello I have a problem in my estlint:

> Assignment to property of function parameter
>   'state'. eslintno-param-reassign

on this code:

> state.sideisOpen = action.payload;

```
interface SideBar {
  sideisOpen: boolean;
}

const INITIAL_STATE: SideBar = {
  sideisOpen: true,
};

const sideBar = createSlice({
  name: 'toggleSide',
  initialState: INITIAL_STATE,
  reducers: {
    toggleSide: (state, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) => {
      state.sideisOpen = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { toggleSide } = sideBar.actions;
export { sideBar };
```

Answer (score 21):

Please try to edit your `.eslintrc` file to make the rule less strict for your case:

```js
// .eslintrc
'no-param-reassign': ['error', {
      props: true,
      ignorePropertyModificationsFor: [
        'state',
      ]
    }],
```

Comment: is it possible to fix the error without placing this rule?

Comment: I think it's not possible, but please let SO community know if you find a solution.

Comment: Oddly, this solution worked if I was only modifying an existing array element (e.g. `state[someIndex] = action.payload`), but did NOT work when adding new elements (e.g. `state = [...state, action.payload]`). I tried using `ignorePropertyModificationsForRegex` and setting `props: false`, but I eventually just had to set this rule to `off` completely. :/